# When reading a csv file with cyrillic, the cyrillic is not recognised

Tags: python, pandas, macos, csv, cyrillic

Here is my file example (if I open it in sublime):

```
;osm_id;code;fclass;population;name;lvl;lvl1_name;reg_nsk2_name;geometry
1;26151301;1001;city;535693;Ãîìåëü;2;Ãîìåëüñêàÿ îáëàñòü;Ãîìåëüñêèé;c(31.0131698, 52.4238936)
2;26162465;1005;national_capital;1982444;Ìèíñê;2;Ìèíñêàÿ îáëàñòü;Ìèíñêèé;c(27.5618791, 53.902334)
3;27171628;1001;city;347576;Áðåñò;2;Áðåñòñêàÿ îáëàñòü;Áðåñòñêèé;c(23.6851851, 52.093751)
4;27251066;1002;town;10917;Ëþáàíü;2;Ìèíñêàÿ îáëàñòü;Ëþáàíñêèé;c(27.9981015, 52.7959497)
```

This is how I read it:

```
adm_centres = pd.read_csv("adm_distr_centres_coord.csv", encoding='utf-8', delimiter=';')
print(adm_centres.head())
```

This is what I get:

```
 Unnamed: 0    osm_id  ...  reg_nsk2_name                   geometry
0           1  26151301  ...     Ãîìåëüñêèé  c(31.0131698, 52.4238936)
1           2  26162465  ...        Ìèíñêèé   c(27.5618791, 53.902334)
```

I have tried different encodings that are suggested to use with Russian according to the table in [Standard Encodings](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings), but it did not help.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the example you gave, except for a bunch of columns replaced by `...`.  Is that what you're asking about?  Is the text from Sublime correct?

Comment: ... - this is how PyCharm shows the data frame content (basically, these ... means that PyCharm just skips some columns showing beginning and the end). The question is that several columns from the csv file ('reg_nsk2_name', 'name', 'lvl1_name', 'reg_nsk2_name') contain data in cyrillic, and while reading it this cyrillic in not recognised. For example, instead of Ãîìåëüñêèé  I should get (i guess): Гомель

Comment: I would say you are stuck until you figure out what the proper encoding of the file is.